# $A \subseteq (X,d)$ is compact. Which metric $p$ makes $(A \times A,p)$ also compact and $d: (A \times A,p) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$(X,d)$ is a metric space. And $A \subseteq X$ is a non-empty compact set in the metric space $(X,d)$.

Then, does there exists a metrics $p$ and if so which metrics $p$ make $(A \times A,p)$ compact and $d: (A \times A,p) \rightarrow ([0,\infty),Euclidean metric)$ continuous?

Comment: Is $p((a,b),(c,d))=d(a,c)+d(b,d)$ a metric?

Comment: @egreg yes, I see that

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $\rho$ is any metric on $A\times A$ that generates the product topology on $A\times A$, then $\langle A\times A,\rho\rangle$ is a compact metric space, since $A\times A$ with the product topology is compact. You’re probably seen at least three metrics on $\Bbb R^2$ that generate the product topology on $\Bbb R^2$ viewed as $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$:

$$\begin{align*}
&d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=\sqrt{|x_0-x_1|^2+|y_0-y_1|^2}\\\\
&d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=|x_0-x_1|+|y_0-y_1|\\\\
&d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=\max\{|x_0-x_1|,|y_0-y_1|\}
\end{align*}$$

Each of these is derived from the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ on $\Bbb R$, and of these ways of defining a metric on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ from one on $\Bbb R$ generalizes to give you a way of defining a metric on $X\times X$ from one on $X$. (There are others as well, but these are the most familiar.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: define the metric $p$ on $A\times A$ by
$$
p((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=d(x_1,x_2)+d(y_1,y_2)
$$
You need to prove that this metric induces on $A\times A$ the product topology.
(It's not the only choice.)